# How can you tell someone you want to talk to them over a text based medium?

Tags: verbs, internet

I use chat programs and often confuse people when I say, "I spoke to…" or "I had a conversation with…" people, when they are remote.  People think that I meant that I had a face-to-face or at least a verbal conversation with them.  Has English solved this?

***Is there a verb for text-based correspondence, that I can substitute for the phrases I normally use to indicate a conversation?***

This question is somewhat similar to another question, but it does not really answer my question: 
["Talk with" vs "talk live with"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65786/talk-with-vs-talk-live-with)

Comment: Can't you ***text*** someone?

Comment: I would include 'online'. I.E. I spoke 'online' to or I had an 'online' conversation with. Since you are referencing 'chatspeak' as it were, perhaps there is an acronym or initialism which can shorten 'online'...if not, create one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to say that you *[messaged](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/message_2)* someone:

> **message**, *v. tr.*: to send someone a message, especially in an electronic form

For example:

> I *messaged* Sam on SMS and on Teams, but got no response.